# "What/when is the right time for doing this?"

Tags: word-choice, questions

Which one of the following sounds more natural?

> - **What** is the right time for doing this?
> - **When** is the right time for doing this?

It seems like these both mean the same thing. If they convey different meanings, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither sounds natural to me, in the sense that I would say, and would expect to hear, slightly different versions.  I'd expect to hear *what time...* or *when should*; for example:

> What time will you do this?
>   When should we do this?

Note, this is not to say the phrases in question do not occur; [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+is+the+right+time%2CWhen+is+the+right+time&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *What is the right time,When is the right time* (or with [lower-case w's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+is+the+right+time%2Cwhen+is+the+right+time&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=)) clearly shows that they do, with use of the *When...* form rising steadily since the 1970's.  But as shown by [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+is+the+right+time%2CWhen+is+the+right+time%2CWhat+time%2CWhen+should&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *What is the right time,When is the right time,What time,When should* (or with [lower-case w's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+is+the+right+time%2Cwhen+is+the+right+time%2Cwhat+time%2Cwhen+should&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=)), use of “What time” and “When should” outstrips use of those phrases, perhaps beyond the level attributable to the inherent matching advantage of two-word phrases against five-word phrases.

Also, although I don't know where else it would fit, having “is the right time” plopped down between the first word and the final phrase in the question's examples seems ungainly.